# Lyx Manjaro Linux Errors (pdflatex)

Tags: pdftex, lyx, linux

I just built Lyx on Manjaro linux from pamac (there is an entry from the AUR, see https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/lyx). When I try to view a document in pdf using pdflatex an window pops up saying an error has occured in the external program "pdflatex" and that I should see the logs. Unfortunately I can't find the logs for pdflatex... If I type pdflatex in a terminal, it is up and running.
Also all of the document classes and modules required by the Help - Introduction, Tutorial, ... are missing.
I wonder if I missed a package to install.
Thank you for your answers !

Comment: "an error pops up" is not a sensible problem description.

Comment: Welcome! Please edit your question title so it does not refer to 'Arch'. Manjaro is **not** Arch. If you don't want the title to reveal your use of Manjaro (why not?), 'Arch-based' or 'Arch derivative' would work. Re. the problem: if you, who know what you installed, don't know if you're missing a package, how should we, who have zero idea what you installed, be able to tell you? When you say you 'built' them, what exactly did you do? You can't install an Arch package for Lyx as there isn't one, but I don't see why you'd build TeX Live rather than installing it. No clue about Manjaro.

Comment: Perhaps in tools > Preferences > Paths is helpful to make sure LyX can find your LaTeX installation.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I updated the question with what was missing, and I'll try today your answer @scottkosty.

Comment: Are you sure it is a pdfTeX log it is referring to? Because that would require your TeX installation to be found. If, on the other hand, it can't find `pdflatex`, it would have to be a `lyx` log (or something like that). Does Lyx work except for compiling? (Does that make sense for Lyx? I've never used it.) That is, you can edit files etc.? Try an absolutely minimal document: just "Hello, world!" in US English etc. That shouldn't require any packages beyond those which are part of LaTeX/TeX itself (unless Lyx adds things). Try an editor to see if it's Lyx or all GUI editors.